# Azure DevOps Server: Test attachments (TRX files) are not deleted for old pipeline builds

Tags: team-foundation-server, azure-devops, azure-devops-server

I’m using Azure DevOps Server (on-prem) v2020 Update 1.2 (v18.181.32404.7)

We are preparing to move to Azure DevOps Service (cloud), but our database is huge and we are trying to clean it up.

TL;DR: There are almost 60 GB of test attachments in the `tbl_Content` table, and many of those attachments live on despite the fact that there’s no corresponding record in the `Build.tbl_Build` table.

Looking at the database for the project collection, `tbl_Content` is by far the largest - taking up around 110 GB. I’ve run the following query which identifies “team test” as the owner of almost 60 GB of this:

```sql
SELECT SUM(m.CompressedLength) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS BlobSizeInMB
FROM tbl_FileReference AS r
JOIN tbl_FileMetadata AS m
ON r.ResourceId = m.ResourceId
AND r.PartitionId = m.PartitionId
WHERE r.PartitionId = 1
AND OwnerId = 4
```

The result of this query:
[image: 59 GB]

I’ve crafted a query which will show me the attachments (content) for a specific build. Here’s an example, where I run the query for build 64447, which belongs to build definition with ID=600:

```sql
SELECT
r.FileId,
r.ResourceId,
r.CreationDate,
a.FileName,
bc.BuildUri,
bc.BuildId,
bc.BuildNumber,
bc.BuildDefinitionId,
bd.DefinitionName,
r.DeletedOn,
b.BuildId as BuildIdFromBuildTable,
CompressedLength / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS BlobSizeInMB
FROM tbl_FileReference AS r
LEFT JOIN tbl_FileMetadata AS m
ON r.ResourceId = m.ResourceId
AND r.PartitionId = m.PartitionId
left join tbl_Attachment a on r.FileId = a.TfsFileId
left join tbl_TestRun tr on a.TestRunId = tr.TestRunId
left join [tbl_BuildConfiguration] bc on tr.BuildConfigurationId = bc.BuildConfigurationId
left join Build.tbl_Definition bd on bc.BuildDefinitionId = bd.DefinitionId
left join tbl_Content content on content.ResourceId = r.ResourceId
left join Build.tbl_Build b on b.BuildId = bc.BuildId
WHERE r.PartitionId = 1
AND OwnerId = 4
AND BuildDefinitionId = 600
AND bc.BuildId = 64447
ORDER BY r.CreationDate DESC
```

This gives me a bunch of records that look like this:
[image: orphaned content]

So, I can see that these attachment records DO exist, and are taking up space in `tbl_Content`, but because the `BuildIdFromBuildTable` column shows a `NULL`, we can see that there is no record for any build with ID 64447 in the `Build.tbl_Build` table (I also checked `dbo.tbl_Build` just to be safe).

So it looks like even though the build was deleted a while ago, the attachments for that build still live on, and are taking up many GB of data in our TFS DB.

I’ve tried running the `tfsbuild destroy` command on the collection for the correct project and a date range surrounding the date of this build, however it says that no deleted builds were found.

How can I get rid of this sizable amount of orphaned build attachment data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by doing the following:

1. Running `TfsConfig deleteTestResults`
2. Running the `Cleanup TestManagement Database` job,
3. Running `EXEC prc_CleanupDeletedFileContent 1` and `EXEC prc_DeleteUnusedFiles 1, 0, 1000`

This took about 26 GB off the database. Many thanks to @WeiyingZhang from Microsoft who suggested #1 over at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-Server:-Test-attachments-T/10490633?viewtype=all